# Obtain an image url

Tags: forms, media, database, uri

I've a module that in the .install creates a table. In that table I have to save the information of one image, that's imagen_leyenda.

[image]

I obtain that image from a form, that I have created in my custom module. To save that image, I have the next code:

```
function guardar_leyenda(&$form_state,$values){
        $icono = $form_state['step_information'][1]['stored_values']['icono'];
        $query = db_insert('leyenda')->fields(array('imagen_leyenda','texto_grande','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin'));
        $query->values(array($icono,$texto2,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),NULL));
        $query->execute();
```

Now, what I need is to obtain the url of that image, but as you can see in the table, the id of the image is store, and what I need is the name of the image.

Is there any way to do that? Or maybe, have I to change something of the previous code?

Thank you very much!

EDIT 1:

This piece of code is the form icono

```
function form_leyenda_editar(&$form, &$form_state){

    $form['icono'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Icono'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
        '#status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
        '#progress_message' => 'One moment while we save your file...',
        );
```

So, after when the user upload an image, drupal generates the id stored in imagen_leyenda.

Comment: Hi, what's the stored id? A File ID generated by Drupal?

Comment: Yes, I think. Drupal generates that id.

Comment: What's the id ? The 1 after $form_state['step_information'] ?

Comment: that $form_state is the form "icono", I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you store the file ID, you can fetch the value from the database and obtain the image URL like this:

```
$file = file_load($file_id);
$image_url = file_create_url($file->uri);
```

Also, you can get the uploaded image with custom dimensions with `image_style_url($style, $image_url)`. You can configure styles here `admin/config/media/image-styles`.

Comment: I think that is a very logical solution, but it doesn't work. $file is false... so I don't realy know what is that number that drupal stores in the table... any other idea?

Comment: Hmm, you should check the `file_managed` table to be sure it's not a file ID. Maybe your call to file_load() is made too early but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: OK. I have seen that is not the file id. Id 342 and 343 doesn't exit in that table. So maybe, I have to change my question and ask how to save in the correct way the images programatically.

Comment: You can use `file_save_upload` to save your file. There's a lot of doc on the interweb ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. You answer help me to find the correct solution. What I have done is save the image in file_managed table as here https://www.drupal.org/node/2313337, and then use the code that you have said. Thank you again